Error while loading shared libraries in privileged Docker container when trying to execute man in bash after kernel update
This is the exact and complete error message:

man: error while loading shared libraries: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: cannot apply additional memory protection after relocation: Permission denied

I think it has something to do with the kernel update my Ubuntu 22.04 got yesterday. It uses kernel 6.8.0-40-generic now.
$ uname -a
Linux Jellyfish 6.8.0-40-generic #40~22.04.3-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Jul 30 17:30:19 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Before the update, I used the kernel 6.5.0-45-generic.
I can execute man without problems in the same docker container in which I got the error above, when I'm booting into the old kernel 6.5.0-45-generic. That is despite the fact that I built the image and ran the container for the first time when using the new kernel 6.8.0-40-generic.
This is my Dockerfile:
FROM kalilinux/kali-rolling:latest

ENV TZ="Europe/Berlin"
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV TERM=xterm-256color

# Install Kali Full
RUN rm -fR /var/lib/apt/ && \
    apt-get clean && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y ca-certificates && \
    apt-get install -y software-properties-common kali-linux-headless --fix-missing && \
    echo 'VERSION_CODENAME=kali-rolling' >> /etc/os-release

# Add NodeJS repo
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_lts.x | bash -

# Some system tools
RUN apt-get install -y openvpn iputils-ping man-db git colordiff colortail unzip vim tmux xterm zsh wget curl telnet strace ltrace tmate less build-essential python3-setuptools python3-pip tor proxychains proxychains4 zstd net-tools bash-completion iputils-tracepath nodejs

COPY ./lab_kzi.ovpn /home/

CMD ["bash", "-c", "openvpn /home/lab_kzi.ovpn >& /dev/null & exec bash"]

WORKDIR /home/

I built the image with
$ docker build --no-cache -t hackthebox_lab .

I also use a docker-compose.yml file:
version: '3'
services:
  htbcontainer:
    image: hackthebox_lab
    privileged: true
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    sysctls:
      - net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=0
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true

I started the container the first time with docker-compose run -i htbcontainer. For later uses I usually use the same container and start it with docker start -i hackthebox-htbcontainer-run-a8e9b92d76dc, or whatever the given container name is.
Update: I think, the problem is caused by the privileged attribute in the docker-compose.yml file (along with the kernel update, because in the kernel before it worked). When I run
$ docker run -it --rm --privileged --cap-add NET_ADMIN --sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=0 hackthebox_lab

I get the same error when trying to execute man whereas when I run
$ docker run -it --rm --cap-add NET_ADMIN --sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=0 hackthebox_lab

(without --privileged) then I can execute man without problems.
Now unfortunately I cannot just omit the privileged attribute, because then openvpn does not work inside the container. I also don't want to stick to an old kernel to keep my container working.
So does anyone have an idea if I either can

get openvpn to work in my container without the privileged attribute or
fix the shared libraries error when using the privileged attribute

Using the kernel 6.8.0-40-generic?
Another Update:
Trying to execute tcpdump inside my container throws the same error as man. I think the reason for that is AppArmor. After executing
$ sudo apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.man

which deactivates the associated profile, I can execute man inside the container. But for security reasons, that's maybe not a good solution.
I also found the possibility to pass an option security_opt to docker-compose. My docker-compose.yml file looks like this now:
version: '4'
services:
  htbcontainer:
    image: hackthebox_lab
    privileged: true
    security_opt:
      - "apparmor=docker-default"
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    sysctls:
      - net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=0
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true

It applies the AppArmor profile "docker-default" to the container, which causes that I can execute man and tcpdump without errors. Unfortunately this setting seems not to be persistent for the created container, because when I exit the container and then start it again, the errors are back. One solution for that would be to create a new image from the container with docker commit and then start a new container from that new image with the security_opt option. But that doesn't seem like a practicable solution to me.
Shouldn't the security_opt option be persistent for the container? Or can I somehow pass that option again when restarting the container?
